# Можно ли добавить подписчиков в телеграмм канал через api?

Tags: python, парсер, api, telegram, автоматизация

Спарсил подписчиков из другого чата и хочу добавить в свой канал. В свою группу добавить не проблема. И готовые скрипты есть, и api тг позволяет.
В канал можно добавить подписчиков вручную. Но можно ли это автоматизировать? Предпочтительно на python.

Comment: Можно и автоматизировать, у телеграмма открытый протокол, можете ваять что хотите, но через бот апи - не выйдет.

Comment: Немного не понимаю, как это делать

Comment: 1) Найти библиотеку, ознакомиться с ее документацией, и реализовать как написано в документации
2) Прочесть документацию по протоколу телеграмм, реализовать минимальный набор обязательных методов, реализовать нужный вам метод, использовать только что реализованный вами метод.